# CXAnswerCallAction not running after answering call

Tags: php, swift, voip, callkit

I have implemented VOIP calls in my application and I am trying to show a screen when the user answers a call.

VoipNotificationManager.swift

```
// Handle incoming pushes
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let callManager = CallManager()
    let id = UUID()

    callManager.reportIncomingCall(id: id, handle: "Assistant")
}
```

CallManager.swift

```
// MARK: Incoming calls
func reportIncomingCall(id: UUID, handle: String) {
    let update          = CXCallUpdate()
    update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: handle)
    update.hasVideo     = true
    
    provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: id, update: update) { error in
        if let error = error?.localizedDescription {
            print("Report incoming call error: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Call reported")
        }
    }
}


// Runs the user answers a call
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
    print("Call answered")
    
    action.fulfill()

    // Show view
}
```

When I run the PHP script (check last code snippet for the PHP code), I receive a call but when I answer the call, the `CXAnswerCallAction` function doesn't run.

But the `CXAnswerCallAction` function runs when I run the app and click on a button which replicates an incoming call like so (this method doesn't involve a PHP script):

```
// Call button
Button {
    let callManager = CallManager()
    let id = UUID()
    callManager.reportIncomingCall(id: id, handle: "Assistant")
            
} label: {
    Text("Call")
}
```

Also, here's the PHP code I run to receive a call:

```
if ( defined("CURL_VERSION_HTTP2") && (curl_version()["features"] & CURL_VERSION_HTTP2) !== 0) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $body ['aps'] = array (
                           "alert" => array (
                                             "status" => 1,
                                             "title"  => "Assistant",
                                             "body"   => "Incoming Video Call",
                                             ),
                           "badge" => 1,
                           "sound"  => "default",
                           "voip" => true
                           );
    $curlconfig = array(
                        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/token",
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>true,
                        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($body),
                        CURLOPT_SSLCERT =>"App.pem",
                        CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD => "Pass",
                        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
                        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
                        );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlconfig);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($res === FALSE) {
        echo('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
} else {
    echo "No HTTP/2 support on client.";
}
```

I don't think there are any issues with the script as it runs with no issue and when I run it, the device receives a call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `CallManager` will be getting released as soon as `pushRegistry` returns (since it's initialised as a local variable inside `pushRegistry`) so by the time the call is answered there will be no `CXProviderDelegate`.

You should initialise one instance of `CallManager` early in your app lifecycle and use this instance throughout the app.

For example, you might make `CallManager` a singleton and use `CallManager.shared` in your `VoipNotificationManager.swift` and elsewhere:

```
class CallManager: CXProviderDelegate {
    
    static let shared = CallManager()

    // private init to prevent other instances
    private init() {
        // probably create CXProvider and set CXProviderDelegate here
    } 

    ...
```